# google maps markerwithlabel not displaying in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-maps

I'm not exactly sure on how to use this external library, it seems I need to make another request to get the markers to show up but I'm not sure of the best way to do it in mvc.

Error I am getting is: `MarkerLabel_.getSharedCross is not a function`

Points just contains an array of Lats/Lngs

```
function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: points[0],
        zoom: 10
    });
    for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({ 
            position: points[i],
            draggable: true,
            map: map,
            labelContent: "$425K",
            labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(22, 0),
            labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
            labelStyle: {opacity: 0.75},
            icon: "../Content/Images/map-icon.png"
        });
        marker.setMap(map);
    }
}
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MyKey&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Custom/marker-with-label.js"></script>
```

Comment: You should be getting some console error in your browser, don't you?

Comment: Added error message, I've read elsewhere that you need to make a seperate request to get the markers to show up so I dont think initMap works but I can't figure out how to do it in mvc.

Comment: what you have in `points[0]`?

Comment: Its an array that collects my model data and saves the lats/longs and displays them. It works fine if I just use the regular google method for markers but when I try to use MarkerWithLabel, it stops working.

Comment: Try `var marker = new google.maps.Marker`? what version of maps you are using?

Comment: I'm trying to use an external javascript plugin
http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerwithlabel/1.0.1/examples/basic.html

Comment: Oh. But I think google maps have markers right? Anyways.. Can you try creating a **[fiddle here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/)**